# How to identify predatory publishers/journals

Tags: publishers, disreputable-publishers

What are the best strategies for assessing if a journal is a "vanity" or "predatory" journal that should be avoided (both for publishing in and reviewing for)? For example, how would one go about determining if a journal/publisher belongs on [Beall’s List of Predatory Open-Access Publishers](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/)?

Comment: In mathematics at least, simply refusing to ever pay anything to get your work published should do the trick.  I gather that trying this strategy in certain other fields (e.g. biology?) may weed out some legitimate -- and even prestigious -- journals.

Comment: Beall's answer is up now, here: http://scholarlyoa.com/2012/08/04/criteria-for-determining-predatory-open-access-publishers/

Comment: Many of the criteria in [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/32403/820) also apply for more general fields.

Comment: The original list of predatory publishers [went offline](http://retractionwatch.com/2017/01/17/bealls-list-potential-predatory-publishers-go-dark/). Here is an [archived copy](https://clinicallibrarian.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/bealls-list-of-predatory-publishers/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam) (Yes, it’s newer, but it also has better answers, not that the answer to this is bad.)

Comment: Check out the blog [Flaky Academic Journals](http://flakyj.blogspot.com/). Interesting read.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right call but you can simply look at who publishes in the journal in question. If there are some well-established researchers who publish, there are little chances that the journal is a predatory one.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft you're a mod now, you can merge these two questions.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, you should probably publish in the same venues that you read and cite.  Presumably those are reputable.

Now to describe low-quality vanity publishers.  Two essential characteristics are:

1. The publication of very low quality material.  This is usually immediately recognizable to any expert.  Sometimes it's obvious to anyone; for example, [read this abstract](http://www.scirp.org/Journal/PaperInformation.aspx?paperID=2210&JournalID=160).
2. A business model in which the author (rather than the reader) pays the publisher.  Of course, this by itself isn't necessarily indicative of a low-quality publisher (think PLoS).   But low-quality publishers can't make money off of subscriptions, since they provide no content of value.

Additional common characteristics of such publishers are:

- Mass e-mails (spam) to academics, especially when the recipients include researchers in unrelated fields.  These e-mails may request submission of conference presentations, papers, or book manuscripts, or may contain invitations to journal editorial boards.
- A high number of prominent typographical errors in text attributable to the publisher.  For instance, at the beginning of [this article](http://www.benthamscience.com/open/tonumj/articles/V004/1TONUMJ.pdf) "abstract" is mistakenly spelled "abstarct".

Comment: I love the example in your point 1! What a headache!

Comment: Elsevier is known to send such unsolicited an irrelevant mass emails: https://phylogenomics.blogspot.com/2012/03/elsevier-bringing-us-conference-spam.html Does it fit your criteria?

Answer (score 3):

*In addition to* [the answer already offered](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2159/19627), you can use a tool such as the one developed by [ULiège Library](https://explore.lib.uliege.be/discovery/search?vid=32ULG_INST:ULIEGE) to help you in your decision.

Their tool, [*Compass to Publish*](https://app.lib.uliege.be/compass-to-publish/test),  "uses a criteria-based evaluation to quantify the degree of authenticity of open access journals requiring or hiding article processing charges."

Even if you don't use their plat-form, their set of criteria / tests can be extremely useful to guide your judgment.

> ## What are the criteria?
>
> *Compass to Publish* uses an evaluation method based on 26 criteria which take the form of questions. These criteria and questions are the
> result of the critical and analytical work of the [team
> behind](https://app.lib.uliege.be/compass-to-publish/pages/9/About)
> *[Compass to Publish](https://app.lib.uliege.be/compass-to-publish/pages/9/About)*,
> who have* *examined the practices of a significant number of predatory
> journals and publishers. This examination was then followed by a
> qualitative survey and selection of criteria developed by trusted
> lists and directories, as well as checklists for the identification of
> predatory journals, including:
>
> - the ["Transparency and best practice" checklist of the Directory
>   of Open Access Journals](https://doaj.org/apply/transparency/)
>   (DOAJ) and the [basic criteria for inclusion in the
>   DOAJ](https://doaj.org/apply/guide/)
> - [the list of criteria for the identification of predatory journals
>   developed by Eriksson &
>   Helgesson (2016)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11019-016-9740-3)
> - [the v.1.1 criteria version for the identification of predatory
>   journals developed by Cabells (a for-profit
>   company)](https://blog.cabells.com/2019/03/20/predatoryreport-criteria-v1-1/)
>
> Looking at the full range of these criteria, we only retained those
> that are:
>
> - truly incriminating and easy to check to ensure user-friendliness;
> - sufficiently relevant and clear;
> - easy to use and check for users.
>
> Some information regarding journal policies and procedures can be very
> hard and/or time-consuming to verify. We deliberately decided not to
> include this type of criteria in the evaluation process in an effort
> to ensure user-friendliness.

Comment: +1 This looks very useful, not only for assessing a specific journal, but also to learn about potential red flags.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest another approach: You have already performed a literature review for your introduction. What journals are your references published in? Have you ever cited a paper in the journal you are thinking about submitting to?

Answer (score -2):

There is an established framework for researchers: [Think. Check. Submit.](https://thinkchecksubmit.org/)

> 1. **Think**: Are you submitting your research to a trusted journal? Is it the right journal for your work?
> 2. **Check**: Use our [check list](http://thinkchecksubmit.org/check/) to assess the journal.
> 3. **Submit** Only if you can answer "yes" to the questions on our [check list](http://thinkchecksubmit.org/submit/).

The resource is [available in over 40 languages](https://blog.doaj.org/2018/12/19/survey-reveals-need-for-good-guidance-about-trustworthy-places-to-publish-research/) as of 2018. If you want a more personal summary of such criteria, see [qsp on why you don't need a list](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/83776/32575).

Note that an analysis of the numbers shows that *[The "problem" of predatory publishing remains a relatively small one and should not be allowed to defame open access](http://blogs.lse.ac.uk/impactofsocialsciences/2018/09/25/the-problem-of-predatory-publishing-remains-a-relatively-small-one-and-should-not-be-allowed-to-defame-open-access/)*. Researchers are generally smart enough to not fall in obvious traps; what's left is mostly problems with peer review which exist anywhere, but mostly in journals with scarce transparency.

Comment: Right now this is essentially a link only answer to your checklist. Can you list some of the categories or key stumbling blocks?

Comment: I think it's better to refer to the checklists hosted there, so that the information does not get stale. We could quote the titles of the sub-lists from http://thinkchecksubmit.org/check/ but I personally don't see a usefulness in that. I don't oppose someone editing my answer that way.