# Is submitting a video on my research paper for ICCT 2017 conference beneficial?

Tags: conference, research-undergraduate

I have submitted my paper here, http://www.iacst.org/iacst/Confe...

They waived my fee and asked me to submit a video file representing my paper. They also told me that
“ Journal recommendation is for oral or poster presentation authors.” 
I am wondering, is it beneficial? The Paper is on my semester project.

Comment: This conference seems kind of scammy to me. See [How can I determine the quality of a conference?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/how-can-i-determine-the-quality-of-a-conference)

Comment: My paper is on semester project so I am not looking for  impact factor. What I am looking for is a platform to have some publication. Is it beneficial to have my paper in this confrence, in any way?

Comment: This is a bad conference.

Comment: I know it is not a good conference. My paper too is not a good one. What I am trying to ask is "Is it in any way beneficial to publish a paper in "bad" conference?"