# ATINER - is this a legimate conference? pros and cons?

Tags: conference, disreputable-publishers

**Background:**
A close acquaintance of mine is a tenured faculty member at a minor US college, having worked there for several decades. They are very well respected for their contributions to the college, students, and community, but they really haven't played a research role. This individual isn't the best when it comes to navigating the perils of the Internet, which brings us to the scenario and question...

**Scenario:**
For both fiscal and, I suppose, for personal reasons, they want to submit a paper to the [ATINER](https://www.atiner.gr/cbc) conference. I think that submitting a few papers may change their title and pay grade, which would help them before moving towards retirement within the next decade, as their family has some financial issues.

**Question:**
Is this a legitimate conference, and what risks of participating? It appears on librarian [Beall's List](https://beallslist.weebly.com/) of potentially predatory conferences. However, from my inspection, it seems to be established, but perhaps low quality. I cross-referenced a couple of their past speakers and the talks do indeed appear on actual people's CV's.

So, to reiterate, my acquaintance is not a researcher, per se, nor desires to be known as one. With that in mind, what are the pros and cons of submitting a paper and giving a talk? I mainly want to protect my friend from harm.

Comment: I closed your question since we do not like to evaluate individual conferences (see [this](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734)), but the proposed duplicate may help you (in particular point 6 of [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/80307/7734)). Once you decided this, you could ask a question about whether it’s reasonable to visit a predatory conference knowingly.

Comment: *I cross-referenced a couple of their past speakers and the talks do indeed appear on actual people's CV's* – That’s not necessarily a good criterion. People may just not have noticed that the conference as what it was, or they intentionally used it to boost their CV because whoever evaluates them doesn’t notice.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for the feedback. Your second comment raises a good point. I'll consider the linked answer.