# WCAM speaker invitation: scam, and how does it work?

Tags: conference, scams

I usually receive many emails from scam journals asking me to publish my work there. And as I understand the scam is that they charge you a lot of money for that, and/or they steal your authors' rights.

But I recently got a different email (and a reminder) from Ms. Elsa Wang about a conference [9th Annual World Congress of Advanced Materials 2022 (WCAM-2022)](https://www.bitcongress.com/wcam2022-japan/) in Tokyo, where I'm supposed to be an **invited speaker**/chair:

> On behalf of committee and based upon your outstanding contribution in
> this field, we cordially welcome you to deliver a presentation as
> Speaker/Chair regarding your recent work [...]

The rest of the email is pretty well written, and the website claims to have important speakers who I recognize and have a pretty good CV. I guess this email is a kind of scam, but it's not clear to me how the scam would go.

So do you confirm this email is a scam? If so, where is the trap? (I guess all expenses are covered for invited speakers usually, no?)

Comment: Not every reputable conference covers all expenses for their invited speakers - some will just not have the budget for this. And in a scam, bait-and-switch tactics are common.

Comment: Possibly related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-conference-is-reputable

Comment: I  deleted the reference to a specific person - I'm not sure we should be doing that.

Comment: The key point is how much registration you still have to pay.  Unless the email *explicitly* states you will have to pay nothing, or states the discounted registration fee, it’s likely a vanity trap where you will have to pay registration and everything else (travel, hotel etc).  This kind of invitation is generic.

Comment: You'll have to pay money to register for something, it won't be free to attend.

Comment: I got a similar email from this conference. It asked me to speak about RF superconductivity. Not my field. Definitely scammy if you ask me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A good technique to research questions of the form "is *X* a scam?" is to google "*X* scam".

I just googled "Annual World Congress of Advanced Materials WCAM scam".

One of the first hits is [someone's blog](https://dftwft.wordpress.com/2018/02/03/going-to-china-for-a-conference-part-1/), which describes the author's experience:

> I’m answering a spam email from BIT Life Sciences, which inviting me
> to their WCAM-2018 conference in Xiamen, China. I suppose the
> conference is real (see the cover picture), but for sure it is a
> predatory conference from a for-profit organization.
>
> So, I created a fake email with a fake name and started contacting Ms.
> Elsa Xing, who sent me the spam email.
>
> ...

followed by a hilarious e-mail exchange with the scammer.  TLDR: the scammer wants your money.