# The meaning of "if any" in journal print charges description

Tags: publications, funding, translations

I saw the following in a journal homepage at  http://www.pphmj.com/journals/jpanta_author_information.htm

> **Print Charges:**
>   To defray the publication cost, authors are requested to arrange print charges of their accepted papers at the rate of US$ 40 per page from their institutions/research grants, if any.

I don't understand the meaning of **if any** in the above sentences. I have a paper with no grant. Should I pay any thing?

Comment: This sentence turns up in very close varieties for multiple journals and conferences author guidelines. In some case it is followed by different explanatory sentences (different or no charges for authors from specific countries or a number of charge-free copies every or only the corresponding author will get). These sentences might change the meaning of "if any". (For example to " if there are any charges, if there are any printed copies you want".)

Comment: It means "We don't know anything about scholarly publishing and we don't care, just give us your grant money"

Comment: $40 per _page_?!

Comment: $40 per page (or even more) would have been pretty standard in the last century.  But nowadays (as noted) unusual.

Comment: The first [google result for "journal page charges"](https://www.google.com/search?q=journal+page+charges) shows that, as recently as 2011, The Astrophysical Journal (which has a top-10 impact factor for astronomy and astrophysics) charged $110 per page.  They've changed to "quantum" charges, but the concept is the same.  No reason page charges should be considered indicative of poor practices.

Comment: @GEdgar It really depends on the journal (and field). It isn't unusual at all for a journal that doesn't have other additional fees to charge $40 per page or to have a flat fee that averages out to well over $40 per page. In some fields, the move towards open access publishing means that valuable library subscriptions aren't a sufficient means of income, and also many good journals subsidize the publication costs for submissions from certain countries or in other circumstances where there is a financial difficulty.

Comment: The Journal of Neuroscience is one of the top journals in my field and the main journal of the Society for Neuroscience, the biggest professional organization in the field. Publication charges are $1260 for members and $1890 for non-members. I'd estimate about 15 pages is fairly typical for a research paper in that journal, so that's about $100 per page.

Answer (score 65):

In my field (political science), a non-open access journal that charges publication fees clearly raises a red flag. But apparently publication fees in other fields are common for subscription-based journals (see comments). It might be just a coincidence then that Pushpa Publishing House is a [predatory publisher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals) that appears on "[Beall's List](https://clinicallibrarian.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/bealls-list-of-predatory-publishers/)".

**Don't publish with this journal.**

Comment: Note that although this particular journal may be disreputable, page charges are common in some fields even in the most reputable, well-read journals. Therefore I wouldn't say page charges themselves are indicative of a predatory publisher.

Answer (score 17):

**If** you are at **any** institution or **if** you have **any** grants, these should be used to pay the print charges.

If you don't have these, it implies you pay the charges out of your own pocket-- if you want a printed version of your paper, that is.

Comment: _"if you want a printed version of your paper, that is"_ Nothing in the text seems to say that.

Comment: @JiK what does "print charges" refer to then?

Comment: @astronat It could be an euphemism for "fee we want from everyone, and we can't just write that" ... ie. even without print version, they get 40 per page

Comment: What I wonder is why the journal cares about where the money to pay those charges comes from.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam: I guess they want to make authors authors think about the money as grant money rather than their own money.  People are typically much more willing to spend money when they don’t think of it as their own.

Comment: @PLL _We can ask for high amounts, because its not your money but the money you got for doing research._ Gotcha. Sounds a lot like everything in science, like lab supplies.

Answer (score 14):

Another way of reading the sentence is:

> If you have an institution/research grant, then the page charges of
>   $40 per page can be paid from that - otherwise, you as the author are required
>   to organise payment the page fee from other funding sources.

Comment: Even then... other funding sources, but if you have none,  I'm guessing they waive entirely.

Comment: Possibly, but that information is not clear from the original question.

Comment: I conclude it from the terms *requested* rather than *required* and the use of "if any".  But you're right,  it is not certain.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is another interpretation that sometimes applies, though I can't say that it does here. For some journals, in some situations, if you don't have institutional or grant funds to pay page charges they are just forgiven and won't accrue to the author(s). I can't say how prevalent this is, but it has occurred (one of my mathematics papers, in fact).

But you should ask the editor what happens if you have no source of funding other than yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The **if any** is applicable to **their institutions/research grants**.  So, this sentence basically means:
*The author has to pay from his/her own pocket if he/she cannot get it funded from his/her institution/research grants.*