# Is there a list of reputable open-access-only publishers?

Tags: journals

Many new publishers have recently appeared because of the open access model (they do not need to struggle with sale & marketing). Some of them are shady business efforts, but some have strong scientific standards and their journals are reliable.

[Beall’s List of Predatory Open-Access Publishers](https://web.archive.org/web/20170111172306/https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/) lists unreliable publishers. Is there any resource listing reliable Open-Access journals? Such list can introduce us reputable publishers we have not come across yet.

The answer to the question "*how to identify*" can be found [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals).

Comment: Just as you would with non-open-access publishers: Look at the editorial board, see if there is someone you know on there (if not, stop here); if yes, ask one of these people whether they are actually editors and whether the periodical can be trusted.

Comment: @darijgrinberg not a reliable approach. Many big names do not care to e mentioned here and there. And many journals put their names without permission. The name of someone on the editorial board does not mean s/he is contributing to the journal's editorial process.

Comment: @henning I further edited the question to avoid the duplication. Hope it is close to what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Googlebot: this is why I said to pick someone you know and ask her!