# How do I determine whether "Global Scientific Journal" is reputable or not?

Tags: phd

I have published my paper in Global Scientific Journal. But some scholars are telling me that the journal is not reputable. How do I determine if Global  Scientific Journal is reputable or predatory?

Comment: Using capitals like that is very poor form and not reputable at all.

Comment: The general answer to this question is here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals

Comment: This post also has some good answers (and the selected answer has some great references) https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam

Answer (score 12):

Although the question may be flagged as "off topic", I think that it is essential to expose predatory journals nonetheless. Hence my answer is:

**Yes, most probably Global Scientific Journal - GSJ Publication is predatory** (which is worse than non-reputable).
My assessment is based simply on the reputable Beall's list  [here](https://beallslist.weebly.com/standalone-journals.html) (updated two weeks ago, 18 Aug 2019):

> Here we include journals that were not originally on the Beall's list, but may be predatory.
>
> Global Journal of Advance Research on Classical and Modern Geometries
>
> Global Journal of Research on Medicinal Plants & Indigenous Medicine
>
> Global Scientific Journal - GSJ Publication

Comment: I wonder if Beall minds others naming things after him, given that he no longer contributes to the list?