# How to find out if a journal is predatory?

Tags: disreputable-publishers

I am considering the website of [this journal](http://ijemaps.com/) and can't really decide if it is a predatory journal or if it is merely a very obscure journal.  As far as I am aware, it does look to be a real journal and there is no mention of article processing charges, but I cannot find information on the impact factor of the journal and cannot seem to find much more information about it apart from what is on its website.  Do people have any advice on being able to tell when a journal is a predator journal or any signs to look for?

I have checked on various lists of predatory journals online and cannot find it there, although I assume that just because a journal is not on any lists does not mean it is not predatory.

Comment: yeah that looks hella fake

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought but I didn't want to be judgemental.  Basically if it looks fake, it probably is fake?

Comment: Also related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2158/68109

Comment: The linked question has great answers. I'll add one question to ask yourself when you look at any new journal: Why does this journal exist? If there's some brand new academic niche, it makes sense to create a new journal. If the journal covers a broad topic that's already covered in the existing literature, be extra suspicious.

Comment: OK that's good advice, thanks a lot.