# A predatory journal?

Tags: publications, journals, disreputable-publishers, fees

I sent my manuscript to a journal which they accepted for publication without peer review. They asked for a 1000 euro service fee. I requested a withdrawal instead,  to which they replied asking whether I was interested in free publication to their other journal as part of their 'social responsibility policy'.

My question is: does this sound like a predatory journal? Will they be able to snatch my work? (First time researcher here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify predatory publishers/journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals)

Comment: No peer review? Surely arXiv is cheaper than 1000 EUR for nothing, probably not even a guarantee that your paper can be found again in 5 years.