# Invitation to a new conference: possible scam?

Tags: conference, scams

I am a researcher on physics and I was invited to a conference as a speaker at the [1st European Conference on Engineering & Technology ECETECH 2022](https://ecetech.org/). The full expenses (round trip flight tickets, travel insurance, and hotel accommodation booking) will be paid by the organizer of the event. But I am expected to pay 650 euro as a registration fee in advance. My concern is, is the event real or scam to take money from researchers?

Comment: Does the organiser happen to be a Nigerian prince?

Comment: Unfortunately such “conferences” are petty common nowadays. Similarly to predatory publishers, it doesn’t look really good on your resume if you fall for them.

Comment: Hey, I am giving a party. I will pay for your drinks and dinner, there is just a registration fee of 1000 euro. Please let me know if you wish to attend.

Comment: Many aspects from the following questions apply here as well: 1. [How do I identify predatory and low quality journals? With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho) 2. [How to identify predatory publishers/journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals)

Comment: @Greg I was trying to decide recently whether I should include a 'Scams I've been extorted by' section on my resume. I didn't include it in the end, but I might go for it next time

Comment: I looked at the location of their so-called Europe office. Turns out it's a rental agency's office, so I don't think this is trustworthy.

Comment: I have an "Academic Spam" folder in my inbox full of crap like this. An I'm only a PhD student!

Comment: The domain ecetech.org is 3 months old. All the main sponsors domains appear to be less than 2 months old. Nuff said...

Comment: Their Europe office is a web design academy? https://webdesignacademy.eu/html/basic-course/paris/september/

Comment: @Bib Most of the websites are based off templates. 3 of the 4 sites are down as well...

Answer (score 33):

It is shady at very least. Covering a wide range of topics, with barely any mention of the organizing committee or keynote speakers - there is hardly any information to go by at all! Even the information for authors throws a 404.

Another shady bit is the venue - they say it will be in an hotel (and quite nice one at that!), however, this hotel website does not show anything close to be usable as a venue and the photo of the conference room apparently comes from a page of a much larger hotel... [In Nigeria](https://www.trip.com/hotels/lagos-hotel-detail-3920931/eko-hotels-and-suites/?city=783&checkin=2022-03-06&checkout=2022-03-07&adult=1&crn=1).

Comment: Also, the lorem ipsum "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis" under the purported picture of the conference room under "Venue"...

Comment: Also of the "sponsors" there is ThomasKutt Telecom which according to their site claims to do telco work in switzerland. No company with "Kutt" in its name exists in Switzerland. Delarist GmbH does not exist except for this conference page (and the linked webpage is dead). Similarly TomWang Telecom also leads to a dead page.

Answer (score 15):

If the list of topics spans a page, you should already be suspicious. Conferences that have no focus typically imply that they are not where people with deep knowledge in a reasonably well circumscribed area of research tend to go, and that they need to draw from a much wider pool of people.

If there are shady aspects of the conference description, then you should be suspicious. For example, the description says "Only Invited Speakers (Incl. Spouse/Family or Co-Author's) are entitled to Free Round-Trip Flight Tickets, Accommodation and Feeding throughout the conference (courtesy of our sponsors)." That's just bizarre: Why would a conference pay for *spouses and family* to fly to the conference?

Pretty much everything else about this conference strikes me as odd as well. In the end, whether it's a scam I don't know -- it's quite possible that they will actually run the conference, but it seems almost certain that it will be a waste of your time and money: You're going to be surrounded by people who are not in your field and not at the top of their respective fields, so you're going to learn very little and you're not going to get very much credit for speaking there as well.

Comment: (+1) Your first paragraph articulates exactly what I was thinking (but didn't say nearly as well) in [a recent comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/182959/49593) when I wrote *published paper titles suggest inclusion of "everything under the sun"*.